# How i can get the selected term inside a managed metadata column inside our PowerApp list form

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, powerapp

I have a managed metadata column inside my PowerApp edit form, the managed metadata allow single selection only, and i want to get its value inside another field to show/hide the field based on the managed metadata selection. so i try to use `Selected.Value` to get the term as follow:-

[image]

where `DataCardValue9_1` is our managed metadata column, but it did not work. so can anyone advice how i can get the selected term?